# Using Vesta CP to host student projects in a school website

Tags: server, web-hosting, shared-hosting, vesta

I am trying to initiate a small web server for an engineering school to host student projects for different web technologies (PHP, Ruby, node ..) and private Gitlab deployment (at later steps).
The school has it own servers. I am thinking about using VestaCP

I have two questions:

1. Let's say that one of these servers can be accessed globally by "www.school.com". can I add these websites under a specific subdomain, let's say: "projects.school.com/JohnDoe" so that every student can access his own website from the main school website?
2. The current server can't be accessed global YET, is it possible to configure using a local ip address and then change settings when acquiring a DNS address?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

Answering your first question first.. So in VestaCP yes you can have subdomains which can be accessed by student from the main school website, You just have to add the subdomain on the "Web" tab in the VestaCP for example yoursubdomain.school.com same as you add new website.. and your student can host their files/website to that particular subdomain's folder for example yoursubdomain.school.com/Student1 just make the subdomain and after that make directories for each student you have in that subdomain and you are done :)

Answering your second question.. Yes you can install, configure and test your server locally and then once you get static ip for your server you can use that ip for acquiring the DNS address.

Comment: Thank's Anand, I figured out a solution a while ago, but it's always good to have support.
I ended Having a single IP for the server, and DNS resolve config to get local connection accessing directly through the local address.